# Is it possible to download a Tor onion website?

Tags: python, download, tor

I'm trying to download an "onion" site , I was trying to use Httrack and Internet Download Manager, unfortunately with no success.

How can I download a Tor "onion" website in depth of 1/2?

Comment: This is an OFF topic question. You may get a better answer on http://superuser.com/

Comment: It is possible but you have to write a script to do it. The simplest way would be wget or curl from the command line using torify

Answer (score 1):

Httrack does not work with Tor, but you can download TorCap2, start Tor, set proxy to 127.0.0.1:9150 (or other port, check it with netstat), enter program location and parameters. I use wget and it's working great.

Answer (score 1):

Archivarix can download .onion sites. Just enter .onion website address in the "Domain" field here https://en.archivarix.com/website-downloader-cms-converter/ and the system will download it from the Tor network just like a regular website.